# Xfce/Xubuntu: system tray doesn't respect system icon theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes, icons, xfce

How can I force the system tray on the panel to use the icons from the icon theme I set? In other DE's the icons in their respective system trays do change but Xfce keeps using the stock icons in the system tray (the rest of the system does use the custom theme).

Comment: Which Xubuntu do you have? Which is your custom theme? Can you show image?

Comment: Sorry, I should've posted that as well. My icon theme is Ubuntu Kylin. It has support different tray icons than the stock ones in other DE's so the support is there. I have Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try removing this file: `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml` and then restart the panel.

Comment: @luchonacho Thanks for the great suggestion!!! After doing that, I've lost my whole configuration. Xfce is back to all of its default settings so all of my customizations are gone.

Comment: The whole point was to check if there was an error in the configuration file. Now, you can do some debugging. Change the icons (**only**) as you want them to see if it works now.